# Взаимовключение заголовочных файлов

Tags: c++, winforms

Существует две формы WinForms, которые должны обмениваться между собой данными. Как известно, для этого нужно включить заголовочный файл другой формы. Но получается, что форма, включая другую форму, включает и саму себя - процесс становится бесконечным. В итоге выводится ошибка - "Слишком много включаемых файлов". Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Не смешивать представление и данные, выделив для последних отдельный файл с классом для хранения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно заголовочный файл имеет структуру

```
// ===== Начало файла =======
// Если не определен символ MY_FILE_H
#ifndef MY_FILE_H
// определить его
#define MY_FILE_H

// здесь остальные определения и инклуды

#endif
// ====== конец файла =======
```

тогда, сколько бы раз вы его не включили, он включится один раз, а потом определит символ `MY_FILE_H` и остальные разы проверка `#ifndef MY_FILE_H` уже не сработает

Comment: `#pragma once` делает не тоже самое?

Comment: Фактической пользы от этого, однако, никакой. Бесконечное включение прекратится, но исходная задача от этого не решится. Циклического включения не должно быть в принципе. Создавать циклическое включение, а потом разрывать его при помощи include guards - бессмысленная работа.

Comment: Добавлю к комментарию @AnT, что ТС"у надо просто определить неполный тип класса управляемый, примерно так `ref class Form2;`, в заголовочном файле использовать неполный тип, а уже в файле реализации `.cpp` подключить интересующий его заголовок с полным типом

Answer (score 2):

Для решения вашей проблемы может быть 2 варианта.

1. Определить неполный тип в интересующих вас заголовках.
2. Подключить все заголовки в файл 'stdafx.h'.

Определение неполного типа:

> Form1.h

```
ref class Form2;
public ref class Form1
{
    Form1(Form2^ form);
    ...
};
```

> Form1.cpp

```
#include "Form1.h"
#include "Form2.h"

Form1::Form1(Form2^ form)
{
    ...
}
```

> Form2.h

```
ref class Form1;
public ref class Form2
{
    void SomeMethod(Form1^ form);
    ...
};
```

> Form2.cpp

```
#include "Form2.h"
#include "Form1.h"

void Form2::SomeMethod(Form1^ form)
{
    ...
}
```

Все, проблема решена, нет ни зацикливания, ни дублирования типов.